# Who created a DB role?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

How can I find out who created a specific DB role?

I Have a database, with the following DB roles (see the picture below)
but I need to know who created the db_dev role, because there is no change request associated with it.

Maybe it was just created by mistake in the wrong server. (classic)
I would like to know who created it?

Not to blame the person, just to find out and inquire about it. there are a few of us here on holiday at the moment.

How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to find that out by reading the default trace.

below is the script I have used.

```
--===============================================================================================
--To check to see whether a default trace is indeed currently running, execute the following:
--===============================================================================================

SELECT * 
FROM sys.configurations 
WHERE configuration_id = 1568


--===============================================================================================
-- script to read from the default trace:
--===============================================================================================

DECLARE
    @trace_id INT,
    @filename NVARCHAR(4000);  

SELECT @trace_id = id 
    FROM sys.traces 
    WHERE is_default = 1; 
SELECT @filename = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), value) 
    FROM sys.fn_trace_getinfo(@trace_id) 
    WHERE property = 2; 

SELECT HostName, LoginName, DatabaseName, TargetUserName, StartTime, TextData AS [Trace Time] 
    FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(@filename, DEFAULT)
```